# Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key. in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, save, django-admin

#admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from studetails.models import Branches

admin.site.register(Branches)
```

#models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Branches(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('ACTIVE', 1),
        ('INACTIVE', 0)
    )
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    branchname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pro_pic = models.FileField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS)
```

What is the save option I have to place in this model as I am not getting this error?

Comment: what error are you facing ??

Comment: Give us the full traceback of the error. And please provide us with the version of Django you're running.